# Making chart from react e chart fill the parent container

Tags: reactjs, charts

I want to make a chart with react-e-chart.js. Here is the code

```
import "../index.css";
import colorConst from "./constant/color.js";
import ReactEcharts from "echarts-for-react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const LineChart = ({
  xData = [],
  yData = [],
  title,
  seriesData = [],
  width,
  height,
}) => {
  const vw = (1920 * width) / 100;
  const vh = (1080 * height) / 100;
  const vwpx = vw.toString() + "px";
  const vhpx = vh.toString() + "px";

  const option = {
    xAxis: {
      data: xData,
      type: "category",
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: "value",
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: "axis",
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: yData,
        type: "line",
        smooth: true,
        itemStyle: {
          opacity: 0,
          color: "black",
        },
        lineStyle: {
          color: "black",
        },
      },
      {
        data: yData,
        type: "line",
        smooth: true,
        itemStyle: {
          opacity: 0,
          color: "black",
        },
        lineStyle: {
          color: "blue",
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="flex flex-col bg-primary p-[15px]"
      style={{ width: vwpx, height: vhpx }}
    >
      <h1 className="text-[25px]">{title}</h1>
      <ReactEcharts option={option} className="bg-[red] h-full w-full" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I rendered it, i got the following results
[image: React Js Rendering]

It is shown that the chart doesn't completely fill the remaining available space inside the parent container below it. Is there any way to make the chart fill the remaining space of container below it?

I have already use `flexbox` and `h-full` property but it doesn't really work for me

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways of doing this, you can either set the classes `flex flex-1` so that the chart stretches the dimensions of the container, else you can just apply the styles `style={{ width: vwpx, height: vhpx }}` directly on the chart, so that the parent and child are set with the same height!

Would suggest directly setting `vh` and `vw` directly, instead of calculating based on pre defined dimensions (`1920 x 1080`), since I dont know your requirements, I guess there is a reason for this, anyway hope this helps solve your issue!

```
import ReactEcharts from 'echarts-for-react';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export const LineChart = ({ xData = [], yData = [], title, width, height }) => {
  const vw = (1920 * width) / 100;
  const vh = (1080 * height) / 100;
  const vwpx = vw.toString() + 'px';
  const vhpx = vh.toString() + 'px';

  const option = {
    xAxis: {
      data: xData,
      type: 'category',
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: 'value',
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'axis',
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: yData,
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true,
        itemStyle: {
          opacity: 0,
          color: 'black',
        },
        lineStyle: {
          color: 'black',
        },
      },
      {
        data: yData,
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true,
        itemStyle: {
          opacity: 0,
          color: 'black',
        },
        lineStyle: {
          color: 'blue',
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="flex flex-col bg-primary p-[15px] bg-[yellow] "
      style={{ width: vwpx, height: vhpx }}
    >
      <h1 className="text-[25px]">{title}</h1>
      <ReactEcharts option={option} className="flex flex-1 bg-[transparent] h-full w-full" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tailwind-tbpmun?file=chart.js,index.html,index.js)

Comment: wow it works well on me. Thank you for the answer. It's really help a lot!